# Generate smaller quads from a large quad?

Tags: unity

I have a big quad (100x100) and I was wondering how can I generate smaller quads from this big quad?
 Such that I will have multiple small quads and I can add a different texture to each quad.

Comment: What is your application? What have you tried? Isn't it better to do a texture mapping on the big quad instead of assigning a texture on each smaller quad?

Comment: Unity, well using smaller quads will aid me with ai, pathfinding etc

Comment: @Casanova are you sure that you want to mix logic and presentation? You could have 1 big quad for presentation while you've got a grid of 100x100 cells for pathfinding calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply:

1. clone your big quad using [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) (using a prefab or your original Game Object).
2. change the scale of the clone using its [transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html).